Using STUFF to append a string before a file extension
I have a requirement where by I need to append something into the filename which is being stored as a string in SQL server.
The append always needs to occur before the file extension which are always four characters in length (.txt, .csv and .xml).
I've being looking into ways to do this and the one I came across was STUFF and I've written the following query:
select fname, code, stuff(fname, 4, 0, concat('_', code)) as d
from (
select right(a.[Path], charindex('\',reverse(a.[Path]))-1) as FName, b.Code
from table_A as a
left join table_B as b on a.ID_A = b.ID_B
) as a

Which produces the output:

The issue with this is that the code is not in the right location as I want it on the righthand side before the extension as mentioned. I tried using -4 as a way to maybe make it work from the right, but all this returned is a NULL value. Is there a way to make STUFF work from the right and not the left or is there some other function I should be using instead?
Many thanks

declare @s as varchar(100)= 'c:\test\test\test.xls' print stuff(@s,len(@s)-3,0,'extra bit')

I dunno, LEN(fname) - 4 perhaps?

Extensions don't have just three letters. You need to find the location of . first. No T-SQL method counts from the end either. If you expect file names to always have a 3-char extension, you'll have to calculate the dot location with len(@s)-3

Rather than telling us the solution, explain the requirements, and provide sample data and desired results (and don't use images, use table markdown for data)

I managed to get a solution using @siggemannen response. It needed changing to -3 but otherwise worked fine. I can't see how to mark his response as the answer as only allows me to upvote it. If anyone knows how I can mark a comment I will. Otherwise, this now closed. Many thanks all.

You cannot mark comments as a solution, @user1663003 .

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Don't miss Extensions don't have just three letters (as @PanagiotisKanavos wrote) in your sample data.

@user1663003 you can't mark comments. People didn't post answers because the question is unclear and there's no data, just images that can't be copied or tested.

Using basic string functions Substring(), Charindex(), Reverse(), ... - the PATH column could be divided into file_path, file_name, file_extension, file_full_name - giving you options to manipulate parts of the PATH column including the change of the file name as asked in the question.
It could be done using STUFF() function too.
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table table_A (ID_A Int, PATH VARCHAR(128));
Insert Into table_A 
  VALUES  (1, 'C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\XML\ORG_98_20240321_1136_62be22f4_358c_436b_89e7_c247d_f03abc.xml'),
          (2, 'C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\CSV\DATA_EXP_20240913_2346_153a.csv'),
          (3, 'C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\MISC\REP_Revenue_20240613_explained.txt');

Create Table table_B (ID_B Int, CODE VARCHAR(12));
Insert Into table_B
  VALUES (1, '31531'), 
         (2, '20421'), 
         (3, '02213');

1. STUFF() function
Select a.ID_A, a.PATH, b.CODE,
       Substring( 
                   STUFF( a.PATH,
                         Len(a.PATH) - 3, 
                         0, 
                         CONCAT( '_', b.CODE)
                       ), 
                  (Len(a.PATH) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(a.PATH), 1) + 2),
                  120
                ) as NEW_FILE_NAME
From   table_A a
Inner Join table_B b ON(b.ID_B = a.ID_A)
Order By   a.ID_A

/*      R e s u l t : 
ID_A  PATH                                                                                      CODE    NEW_FILE_NAME
----  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ------  --------------------------------------------------------------------  
   1  C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\XML\ORG_98_20240321_1136_62be22f4_358c_436b_89e7_c247d_f03abc.xml   31531   ORG_98_20240321_1136_62be22f4_358c_436b_89e7_c247d_f03abc_31531.xml
   2  C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\CSV\DATA_EXP_20240913_2346_153a.csv                                 20421   DATA_EXP_20240913_2346_153a_20421.csv
   3  C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\MISC\REP_Revenue_20240613_explained.txt                             02213   REP_Revenue_20240613_explained_02213.txt                            */

2. Extracting parts of PATH column
... first create a cte ( named it path_parts )
--   extracting parts of the PATH column
WITH
  path_parts AS
    ( Select     a.ID_A, a.PATH, 
                 SubString( a.PATH, 
                            1, 
                            (Len(a.PATH) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(a.PATH), 1) + 1) 
                          ) as file_path,
                 SubString( a.PATH, 
                            (Len(a.PATH) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(a.PATH), 1) + 2), 
                            100 
                          ) as file_full_name,
                 SubString( SubString( a.PATH, 
                                      (Len(a.PATH) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(a.PATH), 1) + 2), 
                                      100 
                                     ),
                            1, 
                            Len( SubString( a.PATH, 
                                           (Len(a.PATH) - CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(a.PATH), 1) + 2), 
                                           100 
                                          )
                               ) - 4
                          ) as file_name,
                 SubString(a.PATH, Len(a.PATH)-3, 4) as file_extension
      From       table_A a
    )

/*      R e s u l t :       ( for cte path_parts )
ID_A  PATH                                                                                      file_path                     file_full_name                                                  file_name                                                  file_extension
----  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ----------------------------  --------------------------------------------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------  --------------
   1  C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\XML\ORG_98_20240321_1136_62be22f4_358c_436b_89e7_c247d_f03abc.xml   C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\XML\    ORG_98_20240321_1136_62be22f4_358c_436b_89e7_c247d_f03abc.xml   ORG_98_20240321_1136_62be22f4_358c_436b_89e7_c247d_f03abc  .xml
   2  C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\CSV\DATA_EXP_20240913_2346_153a.csv                                 C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\CSV\    DATA_EXP_20240913_2346_153a.csv                                 DATA_EXP_20240913_2346_153a                                .csv
   3  C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\MISC\REP_Revenue_20240613_explained.txt                             C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\MISC\   REP_Revenue_20240613_explained.txt                              REP_Revenue_20240613_explained                             .txt            */

Join this cte to your table_B to add the CODE column value into file_name using CONCAT() function:
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
Select     a.ID_A, a.PATH, a.file_full_name, b.CODE, 
           CONCAT(a.file_name, '_', b.CODE, a.file_extension) as NEW_FILE_NAME
From       path_parts a
Inner Join table_B b ON(b.ID_B = a.ID_A)
Order By   a.ID_A

/*      R e s u l t : 
  ID_A  PATH                                                                                     file_full_name                                                 CODE   NEW_FILE_NAME
------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------------------------------------------------------  ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
     1  C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\XML\ORG_98_20240321_1136_62be22f4_358c_436b_89e7_c247d_f03abc.xml  ORG_98_20240321_1136_62be22f4_358c_436b_89e7_c247d_f03abc.xml  31531  ORG_98_20240321_1136_62be22f4_358c_436b_89e7_c247d_f03abc_31531.xml
     2  C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\CSV\DATA_EXP_20240913_2346_153a.csv                                DATA_EXP_20240913_2346_153a.csv                                20421  DATA_EXP_20240913_2346_153a_20421.csv
     3  C:\Apps\2024\PROJ_001\MISC\REP_Revenue_20240613_explained.txt                            REP_Revenue_20240613_explained.txt                             02213  REP_Revenue_20240613_explained_02213.txt                            */    

See the fiddle here.

@TN I know about extensions, but OP was explicite about it. Read the question. If that was not like in this case the dot could be found the same way as the last backslash.
